# Visualize type arguments of generic inheritance in class designer in VS 2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, inheritance

Is there a possibility to visualize the type arguments of a generic inheritance in Visual Studio 2010?
If there is a class with a property like

```
Dictionary<KeyClass,ValueClass> DictionaryProperty
```

I can choose to display the base class of that property. But then there is an inheritance to the generic class Dictionary without the type arguments (KeyClass,ValueClass).
I can't find any way to visualize the type arguments in the class designer!

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can see the type arguments by changing the Members Format property in the Class Diagram properties to "Name and Type" or "Full Signature".

Comment: You're right, but that isn't what I'm looking for. I like to see the type arguments at the inheritance line.

Comment: Ah, OK, I understand now, no, I don't see any way of displaying Type Arguments on the Inheritance line in Visual Studio 2010.