# Visualizing type dependencies in golang

Tags: go, types, uml, entity-relationship

How can I visualize how types depend on one another in a complex golang app ?  Is there a way I can generate a UML/ER dependency diagram ?

There are some well known ways to generate call graphs, but I haven't seen a way to generate "Type" graphs.

*detail*

I'm actually looking at a swagger based REST Api definition, so, if there are ways to use swagger to generate type data, that also might be valuable.

Comment: If you were just asking how to show type struct of Golang in UML you might get an answer. But "asking for tool to..." is OT.

Comment: why is a tool for analyzing type dependencies off topic?

Comment: There are several other questions which ask about visualization technology for code bases, w/ up votes.  I would say it would set an odd precedent to close questions about developer tooling: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886836/what-debuggervisualizers-are-already-existing-within-visualstudio-or-net-framew/4886864#4886864  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540467/visualize-type-arguments-of-generic-inheritance-in-class-designer-in-vs-2010

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic 4. list topic

Comment: Ok, I see, this is in the "find or recommend a software library" category.

Comment: Yes. Most people get struck by that one day :-) But I guess if you omit that last part of your question it will still fall in the category of "too broad" or "opinion based". I don't have any golang background (just googled a bit), but would guess that those type graphs can't be wizardry.